# "copy link" doesn't work on Opera on Android

Tags: bug, status-declined, share-this, mobile-opera

"copy link" doesn't work on [Opera Mobile on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser) (tested with the responsive site):

[image]

Comment: What does your browser console say, the reason is probably in there somewhere.

Comment: @Luuklag [How can I access the browser console on Opera Mobile on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225798/12202)

Comment: Opera on Android is not in the list of [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)